# Property 'data' could not be found in forward class object

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to access the property 'data' of an NSObject (socketIOPacket). When I try to [access this property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMj5W.png), I get a complier error saying  : Property 'data' could not be found in forward class object.

When I set a breakpoint, I can see that this object [does have a data property](http://i.imgur.com/QzIZ8Ke.png)

What am I doing wrong? I am fairly new to objective C.

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong and it probably has something to do with `data`.  (This is as much as we can tell you, since you haven't told us anything.)

Comment: I added screenshots from Xcode. I will add more information if the suggestions below doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the name of the class you're trying to access `data` on? You probably just need to import the .h file into the class from which you're accessing it.

Something like this:

```
#import "ClassName.h"
```

Alternately you have to make sure the property is exposed. If `data` isn't forward facing, i.e. it isn't declared in the header file, then you shouldn't be accessing it anyway.